# Getting http post values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This issue I am having is that I am getting a load of http post data from an external site to my page and am struggling to separate it out and deal with them, I have put an example below:

I was given this code below, however it is in c# and the web app I am using is vb.net. I have been searching online for a couple of days and they were talking about looping through the form collection but I have little experience of using form collections.

I can get the html and plain by using request("html") but when I try and use request("envelope")("from") it just doesn't work.

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
String from = Request.Form["envelope"]["from"];
String subject = Request.Form["headers"]["Subject"];
String plain = Request.Form["plain"];
String html = Request.Form["html"];
String reply = Request.Form["reply_plain"];
}
```

The ideal situation would be something like this:

```
Dim subject as string = Request.Form["headers"]["Subject"]
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access form data in this way:

```
Dim plain As String
If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form("plain")) 
Then
    plain = Request.Form("plain")
End If
```

To access header data, use `Header` property instead of `Form`

```
Dim subject As String
If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Header("Subject")) 
Then
    subject = Request.Header("Subject")
End If
```

Comment: I gave that a go but "subject" is just an empty string. 

"subject" should be returning "test 11" - Do I need to be calling headers somehow?

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers[Subject]"
test 11

Comment: @Dave Example i gave if for accessing `Form` data, but I used `Subject` key and that caused confusion. `Subject` key is part of `Header`. I updated my answer, check it out